# Why some eggs are bile stained?

Tags: microbiology, parasitology, eggs

Why eggs of some helminths( *Diphyllobothrium latum, Trichuris trichiura, Ascaris lumbricoides* etc)  are stained with bile while eggs of other helminths( *Hymenolepis nana, Enterobius vermicularis* etc.) are not?

---

Some [sites](http://www.medicalgeek.com/viva/9483-qs-about-microbiology.html) say that its because, more the lipid content better is the staining with bile of egg, then how eggs of ascaris are bile stained whose outer shell is made of proteins?